# Magento 2 : how to getbaseurl for different website?

Tags: magento2, base-url

I have set the different Base Url for different website views, so How to get the baseUrl for a different websites with getBaseUrl() function.

~~ Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can get BaseUrl by store object. So you will have to first load the store from website. Check below generic code which will give all website's base URLs.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager =  $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$websites = $storeManager->getWebsites();
 foreach ($websites as $website) {
     foreach ($website->getStores() as $store) {
         $wedsiteId = $website->getId();
         $storeObj = $storeManager->getStore($store);
         $storeId = $storeObj->getId();
         echo $url = $storeObj->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
     }
 }
```

If you are using constructor you can directly use \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager instead of objectmanager.

Comment: I'm sorry dude, but you should NOT use ObjectManager under any circumstances. You should add `StoreManagerInterface` into constructor, but not ObjectManager.

Comment: @Yupik: yes you are right. i will modify the sentance.